# Python dynamic multiprocessing

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I am a Python beginner. I managed to run my function in multiple parallel processes, but now I want to refactor it a little bit, and I am lost...

What I want to do is:

1. run main() with 1 - x parameters (keywords)
2. main() should run max. 32/x parallel functions search() in separated pools for each keyword
3. search() is looking for "keyword" string on webpage, once there is "keyword" found in any process (in pool), search() should return url, which is passed to download() function
4. download() function should substitute search() functions in parent pool (in a term of max parallel processes), other pools should still search for keyword
5. repeat for all other pools

Example:

1. main("stack", "overflow")
2. there should be 2 search pools, one for "stack", second for "overflow", each should have 16 search() processes
3. keyword "stack" was found, search() function should be substituted by 16 download() functions; keyword "overflow" was not found, continues in separated pool, separated processes

My current script works like this:

1. Start main()
2. main() spawns 16x search()
3. Once "string" is found in any of search() processes, this particular process starts to download, all others are still trying to search "string" (there is no need for it anymore)

I know I am not very specific, but I don't think you need to see my horrible script to understand what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to do the download directly in the worker process (your `search()` function) after it finds a suitable URL.

BTW, be *very careful* with programs like this. You could inadvertently create a denial-of-service attack. For every site that you visit you should check for and obey [`robots.txt`](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html).